# How can i use Draggable widget with GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following full simple code

```
 import 'dart:developer';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class A2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const A2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<A2> createState() => _A2State();
}

class _A2State extends State<A2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:GestureDetector(
          onScaleUpdate: (detail){
            log('scale is ${detail.scale}');
            log('rotation is ${detail.rotation}');
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

everything is work fine with my following need

1- `log('scale is ${detail.scale}');`

2- `log('rotation is ${detail.rotation}');`

**BUT**

when i wrap the `GestureDetector` into `Draggable` widget, my GestureDetector does not response anymore !

like following

```
      {......
      Draggable(
      feedback: Container(),
      child: GestureDetector(......}
```

How could i solve this problem ?

Comment: why do you want to use drag and GestureDetector all to gather?

Comment: because i need to use scale and rotate that Draggable does not support . also i need to drag data that GestureDetector  does not support .. it is like stickers drag and delete and rotate and so